# P21w light up only with 9 V or more

Tags: lights

I have a P21w bulb on my car that receives 4.5 volts to act as a running light. When I press the fog button on the dash that bulb receives approximately 12 V via the same wire and acts as a fog light.

I would like that bulb to only turn ON when I press the fog button and ignore the 4.7 V (I want the P21w ONLY as a fog light).

Is there a simple and safe way to do this or something that I can buy (already made) to do this?

It could also be a P21w LED that would light up only with 12 V...

Comment: `ignore the 4.7v` ... no  ........... `stop supplying 4.7V to bulb` .... yes ................

Comment: If you remove one running light, does the other one unlit, too? If yes, this is simply a series/parallel connection which could be rewired.

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to mention that I have two bulbs. One on each side of the rear lights of the car. And they are acting as running and fog lights, depending on the voltage they receive. I just want them to light up as FOG LIGHTS and ignore voltages under aprox. 12v.

Comment: Car model and year? Have you googled "year model disable drl" or for the wiring diagram?

Comment: BMW 320D E46 Sedan PostFacelift (2003).

Comment: DLR are Off. I tried everything I know and changed values in NCS Expert. But nothing makes those damn light act only as Fog lights.

Comment: No one can answer this?